# Pretty print for Java

Tags: rascal

I am trying to change the content of a .java file

I got the AST thanks to:

```
ast = createAstFromFile(|project://foo/src/main/Main.java|,true);
ast = doSomeChanges(ast);
```

Then I want to serialize the AST.
Is there a way to get back the source code from an AST?